# “Invalid url to index” in Google Custom Search

Tags: google-custom-search

I want to reindex a page using Google Custom Search.  Google Webmaster Tools says I manage the site.

In Google Custom Search, I go to "Specific URLs" under "Index Now".  I add a URL or two and click "Index Now".  It always says “Invalid url to index”.  Is there some trick to this, like some special formatting I have to do with the URLs?

Anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: Could you post the URLs you are trying to index?

Comment: I'm not wild about posting the actual URLs since it's for a particular client, but they are completely normal looking URLs, e.g., http://www.foo.com.

Comment: Also having this issue. Completely normal URL's. e.g. http://www.example.com/example-page.html. Pages are indexed fine in actual Google search

Comment: I don't have a solution, but this appears related to https.  Can it be that GCS does not support https, even with the recent google "ssh everywhere" push?  I submit my link with http and it works, but not https.  I have both variants verified in webmaster tools.

Comment: I have this same problem too, even though the URLs I am submitting are not using https,  I have a paid custom search account, and the site is verified in Webmaster Tools.  In fact, I can request indexing for them via WMT, but not via CSE, which is annoying since there are a few of them.  I think this form is broken.

Answer (score 1):

From tooltip on that page:

> URLs must be from sites you have [verified in Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2402989).

Comment: Any idea of how this can be done if you do not own the site, but only the data (and you can't add a verification file there)?